# Why is completion of my beforeAll() function not being waited for?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

I have a web app which I am writing automation for, using WebDriver and Jasmine.  This app can be thought of as an online library, where it can load different products, each of which have different content.  This automation is supposed to loop over all the locations within the loaded product and run tests on each one.

Since I am running the automation on different products, the automation takes as input an identifier for the product being tested.  I use that identifier in the beforeAll function to load information from a web service about the product being tested.

```
const identifier = process.argv[3];

describe('product check', function() {
  var appData;

  beforeAll(async function() {
    // this comes from a web service, hence being async
    appData = await getAppData(identifier);
  })
}
```

The automation should then loop over the appData data structure and generate expectations based on its contents.

Now, my understanding of using loops within Jasmine is that you need to need to put your expectations in a function and call that repeatedly within the loop:

```
// this won't work
for(var i = 0; i<appData.numInstances; i++) {
  it('is within a for loop', async function() {
    expect(...); 
  })
}

// it has to be done like this instead
function containsIt(i) {
  it('is within a function', async function() {
    expect(...); 
  })
}

for(var i = 0; i<appData.numInstances; i++) {
  containsIt(i)
}
```

What I am finding is that, if I have my expectations within a function as shown above, the automation doesn't wait for the beforeAll function to finish before the function containing it() is called, so I get an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'numInstances' of undefined`

I have confirmed that getAppData() works correctly, and that appData is being populated within the beforeAll() function.

I realize that I could put the loop over appData within an it(), but that would mean that all my expect() statements are within the same it() block, and I would lose the ability to have meaningful descriptions from it() in my reporting.

What I would like is the ability to have a loop in which the different functions containing it()s are called repeatedly, while still loading my application data in the beforeAll function.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this exact same situation before and I think with newer versions of `Jasmine` you won't face this issue although I am not 100% certain.

Looking at the [docs](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) they have an `async/await` in the `beforeEach` so I am thinking in newer versions it waits for everything to finish in the `beforeEach` (or `beforeAll`) before proceeding to `it`s.

To get around your issue, you can use the `done` callback provided by `Jasmine`.

```
beforeAll(async function(done) { // add done callback to the function
    // this comes from a web service, hence being async
    appData = await getAppData(identifier);
    done(); // call done here to let Jasmine know this beforeAll is done
  })
```

With the `done` callback, the order should now be respected where the `beforeAll` will run and complete before the first `it`.

Comment: I tried this, and it had no effect; I got the same error.  Would you be able to post some of your code where this worked, so I can see if there is some other difference that is making this not work for me?

Comment: This has worked for me in Angular unit testing and not Selenium. If you put a `console.log('after done');` after `done();` and a `console.log('first it');` at the first line of the `it` block, do you see `first it` before `after done`?

Comment: I am still getting the error mentioned in my original post, and neither console.log() message is displayed.  If I change the code to have an it() instead of a for() after the beforeAll(), then `after done` is displayed before the `first it`.

Comment: Oh that is strange. I wonder why an `it` within a for loop causes issues. I am not sure then, sorry.]